# How to specifically sort a DataFrame by reordering rows [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to change the order of this dataframe:

```
    genre       average_voteM
7   Documentary 7.200000
11  Film-Noir   6.606486
4   Biography   6.551788
12  History     6.476688
23  War         6.383735
3   Animation   6.274451
8   Drama       6.159555
14  Music       6.143162
15  Musical     6.124792
17  News        6.000000
```

so that the **genres** are in this order:

```
7   Documentary 7.200000
11  Film-Noir   6.606486
4   Biography   6.551788
12  History     6.476688
23  War         6.383735
17  News        6.000000
3   Animation   6.274451
15  Musical     6.124792
14  Music       6.143162
8   Drama       6.159555
```

The data is IMDB film data from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/stefanoleone992/imdb-extensive-dataset?select=IMDb%20ratings.csv).
I have tried the method A[[7,8]] = A[[8,7]], however this did not work for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort_order = {
    'Documentary':0,
    'Film-Noir':1,
    'Biography':2,
    'History':3,
    'War':4,
    'News':5,
    'Animation':6,
    'Musical':7,
    'Music':8,
    'Drama':9
}

df.sort_values(by=['genre'], key=lambda x: x.map(sort_order))
```

Comment: The 'key-lambda x: x.map(sort_order)' section gives me an error. TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'.

Comment: Try upgrading your pandas version, you're probably running an old one.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter rows using `df.loc`:

```
df.loc[2:len(df),'average_voteM'] = df.loc[2:len(df),'average_voteM'].sort_values()
```

Replace `2` with the start row